# Error when running Tomcat Server in my Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, endorsed

the problem below is fixed and the server runs now. However it keeps printing red messages but then it deletes them and runs... is that normal? Is there any need for fixing it - if so, what?

---

When I created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and tried to run my Apache Tomcat v9.0 Server in which I made all the .sh files executable, it still gave me this error:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/my_name/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat- 
9.0.10/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
```

In all the tutorials and forums I have looked, none of the proposed solutions have helped me. **How can I fix this problem and make my server run properly?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What JRE are you using? The error you're getting seems to indicate that there is an incompatibility between the JRE versions. As mentioned in Tomcat's docs https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html the 'endorsed' feature is not support in Java hence it means that something keeps adding this up to your configuration.

This seems to be an issue with eclipse (or at the least the way it's setup at your system). Try having a look at this eclipse bug link as it may provide so more information about the problem you're dealing:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507338

Comment: thanks so much! Server runs now. However it keeps printing red messages but then it deletes them and runs... is that normal?

Comment: Can you please post a snippet of those messages? Also if the answer was helpful for you please take the time to upvote it.